# SVG has no height in ie11

Tags: css, internet-explorer, svg

I am having issues with an svg, where it's height isn't affecting the parent container which is resulting in some weird position of other elements.

Here is a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bkm4qgvb/3/). If you open this in ie11, you can see that the circles now extend outside of the grey box, rather than making the grey box larger as it does in chrome.

I have tried adding this to the svg as was suggested on another question: `preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin slice"` but it hasn't made any difference.

I've also tried setting the width and height in different ways but still nothing has worked.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background: #fff;
}

.row--flex {
  background: #dedede;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  -webkit-flex-direction: row;
  -ms-flex-direction: row;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.col--6-12 {
  width: 50%;
}

.selector-block {
  padding-right: 45px;
  padding-left: 45px;
}
.selector-block .col--flex-col {
  justify-content: center;
}
.selector-block .col--flex-col > * {
  flex: 0;
}
.selector-block .col--6-12:first-of-type {
  padding-right: 45px;
}
.selector-block .col--6-12:last-of-type {
  padding-left: 45px;
}
.selector-block__icons {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 575px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}
.selector-block__title {
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
.selector-block__title--join {
  top: 30%;
  left: 33%;
}
.selector-block__title--learn {
  top: 56%;
  left: 72%;
}
.selector-block__title--connect {
  top: 76%;
  left: 28%;
}
.selector-block__title.open {
  color: #fff;
}
.selector-block__text {
  display: none;
}
.selector-block__text--mia {
  display: block;
}

.selector-icons {
  max-width: 575px;
  width: 100%;
}

.selector-icon {
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.selector-icon--connect .selector-icon__img {
  fill: #e0b83b;
}
.selector-icon--learn .selector-icon__img {
  fill: #51bab4;
}
.selector-icon--join .selector-icon__img {
  fill: #6e5bb2;
}
.selector-icon--selected .selector-circle {
  opacity: 1;
}
.selector-icon--selected .selector-icon__img {
  fill: #fff;
}

.selector-circle {
  opacity: 0.3;
  transition: all 400ms;
}
.selector-circle--connect {
  bottom: 0;
  right: 48%;
}
.selector-circle--connect .selector-circle__img {
  fill: #e0b83b;
}
.selector-circle--learn {
  top: 50%;
  left: 48%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
.selector-circle--learn .selector-circle__img {
  fill: #51bab4;
}
.selector-circle--join {
  top: 0;
  right: 48%;
}
.selector-circle--join .selector-circle__img {
  fill: #6e5bb2;
}
```

```html
<div class="row row--contained row--flex p--b-100 selector-block bg--white">
    <div class="col--6-12 col__m--12-12">
        <div class="selector-block__icons">
            <svg version="1.1" class="selector-icons" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
                  width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 572.17188 595.41016" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin slice">
                <a class="selector-icon selector-icon--join">
                 <g class="selector-circle">
                  <g>
                   <defs>
                    <rect id="SVGID_1_" x="27.46826" width="323.42432" height="323.41992"/>
                   </defs>
                   <clipPath id="SVGID_2_">
                    <use xlink:href="#SVGID_1_"  overflow="visible"/>
                   </clipPath>
                   <path clip-path="url(#SVGID_2_)" fill="#6F5CA8" d="M350.89453,161.71094c0,89.31152-72.40088,161.71289-161.71338,161.71289
                    c-89.31201,0-161.71387-72.40137-161.71387-161.71289c0-89.3125,72.40186-161.71289,161.71387-161.71289
                    C278.49365-0.00195,350.89453,72.39844,350.89453,161.71094"/>
                  </g>
                 </g>
                 <path class="selector-icon__img" fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M203.63818,99.52637c-0.82422,0-1.49414-0.6709-1.49414-1.49219
                  c0-0.82324,0.66992-1.49316,1.49414-1.49316h28.03516c1.46191,0,2.80273,0.5957,3.77734,1.57129h0.01563
                  c0.95898,0.97363,1.56738,2.32617,1.56738,3.78809v58.00977c0,1.47754-0.59277,2.81836-1.56738,3.79395l-0.10547,0.08887
                  c-0.96289,0.91602-2.25781,1.47754-3.6875,1.47754H146.5874c-1.46191,0-2.81836-0.59277-3.77734-1.56641
                  c-0.97461-0.97559-1.58203-2.31641-1.58203-3.79395v-58.00977c0-1.47656,0.60742-2.81445,1.56641-3.78809h0.01563h-0.01563
                  c0.97461-0.97559,2.33105-1.58789,3.79297-1.58789h28.03613c0.83789,0,1.50879,0.67188,1.50879,1.50977
                  c0,0.82129-0.6709,1.49219-1.50879,1.49219H146.5874c-0.63867,0-1.23242,0.27344-1.67578,0.70215
                  c-0.42578,0.4248-0.68164,1.01758-0.68164,1.67188v58.00977c0,0.63867,0.25586,1.25195,0.68164,1.67578
                  c0.44336,0.4248,1.03711,0.70215,1.67578,0.70215h85.08594c0.62305,0,1.18945-0.26172,1.61328-0.65527l0.0625-0.04688
                  c0.42578-0.42383,0.70215-1.02148,0.70215-1.67578v-58.00977c0-0.6543-0.27637-1.24707-0.70215-1.67188
                  c-0.44043-0.42871-1.03711-0.70215-1.67578-0.70215H203.63818z"/>
                 <path class="selector-icon__img" fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M187.20459,149.7959c-0.83789,0-1.50977-0.66602-1.50977-1.48828
                  c0-0.82324,0.67188-1.49316,1.50977-1.49316h23.19336c0.83789,0,1.50781,0.66992,1.50781,1.49316
                  c0,0.82227-0.66992,1.48828-1.50781,1.48828H187.20459z"/>
                 <path class="selector-icon__img" fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M187.20459,142.07715c-0.83789,0-1.50977-0.6709-1.50977-1.50879
                  c0-0.82227,0.67188-1.49316,1.50977-1.49316h36.73438c0.83789,0,1.50781,0.6709,1.50781,1.49316
                  c0,0.83789-0.66992,1.50879-1.50781,1.50879H187.20459z"/>
                 <path class="selector-icon__img" fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M187.20459,134.3418c-0.83789,0-1.50977-0.6709-1.50977-1.50879
                  c0-0.82227,0.67188-1.49316,1.50977-1.49316h36.73438c0.83789,0,1.50781,0.6709,1.50781,1.49316
                  c0,0.83789-0.66992,1.50879-1.50781,1.50879H187.20459z"/>
                 <path class="selector-icon__img" fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M187.20459,126.60352c-0.83789,0-1.50977-0.6709-1.50977-1.50488
                  c0-0.82227,0.67188-1.49316,1.50977-1.49316h36.73438c0.83789,0,1.50781,0.6709,1.50781,1.49316
                  c0,0.83398-0.66992,1.50488-1.50781,1.50488H187.20459z"/>
                 <path class="selector-icon__img" fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M166.50732,123.60547c2.54492,0,4.8457,1.03223,6.51855,2.70898
                  h0.01465c1.67578,1.67676,2.69824,3.98926,2.69824,6.51855c0,2.54199-1.03711,4.8584-2.69824,6.53418h-0.01465
                  c-1.66211,1.67285-3.97363,2.70996-6.51855,2.70996c-2.54297,0-4.8584-1.03711-6.51953-2.70996h-0.01172
                  c-1.66016-1.67578-2.69824-3.99219-2.69824-6.53418s1.03809-4.8418,2.69824-6.51855h0.01172
                  C161.66455,124.6377,163.96436,123.60547,166.50732,123.60547 M170.92334,128.41602
                  c-1.12695-1.12695-2.69336-1.8125-4.41602-1.8125c-1.7207,0-3.27148,0.70215-4.40234,1.8125l-0.01172,0.0166
                  c-1.13086,1.12598-1.81348,2.67773-1.81348,4.40039c0,1.71875,0.68262,3.29102,1.81348,4.41699h0.01172
                  c1.13086,1.12695,2.68164,1.8252,4.40234,1.8252c1.72266,0,3.28906-0.69824,4.41602-1.8252
                  c1.12695-1.12598,1.8291-2.69824,1.8291-4.41699c0-1.72266-0.70215-3.29004-1.8291-4.40039V128.41602z"/>
                 <path class="selector-icon__img" fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M158.771,149.79688c-0.82227,0-1.49219-0.66699-1.49219-1.48926
                  c0-0.82324,0.66992-1.49316,1.49219-1.49316h15.47461c0.82227,0,1.49219,0.66992,1.49219,1.49316
                  c0,0.82227-0.66992,1.48926-1.49219,1.48926H158.771z"/>
                 <path class="selector-icon__img" fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M203.63818,107.26172c-0.82422,0-1.49414-0.6709-1.49414-1.49316
                  c0-0.81836,0.66992-1.48926,1.49414-1.48926h7.73438c0.82227,0,1.49414,0.6709,1.49414,1.48926v7.73926
                  c0,0.82227-0.67188,1.49316-1.49414,1.49316h-44.46875c-0.83789,0-1.50781-0.6709-1.50781-1.49316v-7.73926
                  c0-0.83496,0.66992-1.50488,1.50781-1.50488h7.71973c0.82324,0,1.50879,0.66992,1.50879,1.50488
                  c0,0.82227-0.68555,1.49316-1.50879,1.49316h-6.22559v4.7373h41.48145v-4.7373H203.63818z"/>
                 <path class="selector-icon__img" fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M182.36279,69.46387h13.53613
                  c0.82227,0,1.49316,0.66992,1.49316,1.49316v34.8125c0,0.82129-0.6709,1.49219-1.49316,1.49219h-13.53613
                  c-0.82227,0-1.49414-0.6709-1.49414-1.49219v-34.8125C180.86865,70.13379,181.54053,69.46387,182.36279,69.46387
                   M194.40967,72.46582h-10.53906v31.79785h10.53906V72.46582z"/>
                 <path class="selector-icon__img" fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M191.65283,78.69238c0,1.3877-1.12695,2.51465-2.51465,2.51465
                  c-1.38477,0-2.50977-1.12695-2.50977-2.51465c0-1.38379,1.125-2.51074,2.50977-2.51074
                  C190.52588,76.18164,191.65283,77.30859,191.65283,78.69238"/>
                </a>
                <a class="selector-icon selector-icon--learn">
                 <g class="selector-circle">
                  <g>
                   <defs>
                    <rect id="SVGID_3_" x="248.74756" y="159.10059" width="323.42432" height="323.41992"/>
                   </defs>
                   <clipPath id="SVGID_4_">
                    <use xlink:href="#SVGID_3_"  overflow="visible"/>
                   </clipPath>
                   <path clip-path="url(#SVGID_4_)" fill="#52BBB5" d="M572.17383,320.80957c0,89.31152-72.40039,161.71289-161.71289,161.71289
                    s-161.71338-72.40137-161.71338-161.71289c0-89.3125,72.40088-161.71289,161.71338-161.71289
                    S572.17383,231.49707,572.17383,320.80957"/>
                  </g>
                 </g>
                 <path class="selector-icon__img" d="M452.68945,268.54102l-40.10156-14.75c-4.37891-1.61328-9.2168-1.61328-13.5957,0l-37.56641,14.52051
                  c-3.22656,1.15137-5.07031,4.14746-5.07031,7.375c0,3.22559,2.07422,5.99121,5.07031,7.14355l40.10156,14.75
                  c2.07422,0.69141,4.37891,1.15234,6.68164,1.15234c2.30664,0,4.60938-0.46094,6.45313-1.38379l9.21875-3.45703
                  c1.15234-0.46094,1.8457-1.84277,1.38477-2.99512s-1.8457-1.84375-2.99609-1.38379l-9.2207,3.45801
                  c-2.99414,1.15234-6.45117,1.15234-9.9082,0l-40.10156-14.51953c-1.84375-0.69141-2.07422-2.30371-2.07422-2.76465
                  s0.23047-2.30566,2.07422-2.99609l37.56641-14.29004c3.22656-1.15234,6.91406-1.38184,10.37109,0l40.09961,14.75
                  c1.38281,0.23047,2.07422,1.15234,2.07422,2.53613c0,1.38184-0.92188,2.53418-2.30469,2.99414l-16.13281,6.22363l-24.42969-9.91016
                  c-0.69141-0.92188-2.30273-1.61328-4.37695-1.61328c-2.53516,0-4.60938,1.15234-4.60938,2.30566
                  c0,1.15137,1.84375,2.07324,4.14844,2.30371l26.96289,10.83203v28.57813c-2.76367,0.92188-4.60938,3.45703-4.60938,6.45313
                  c0,3.91797,2.99609,6.91309,6.91406,6.91309s6.91406-2.99512,6.91406-6.91309c0-2.53516-1.38281-4.84082-3.68555-5.99219
                  c1.8418-1.15332,3.68555-2.53516,5.07031-3.68848c0.46094-0.46094,0.68945-1.15137,0.68945-1.6123v-18.4375
                  c0-1.38281-0.92188-2.30469-2.30273-2.30469c-1.38281,0-2.30664,0.92188-2.30664,2.30469v17.28516
                  c-0.68945,0.69043-1.38281,1.15234-2.30469,1.61328v-23.96875l15.44141-5.76172c3.22656-1.15332,5.30078-4.14941,5.30078-7.375
                  C457.75977,272.45898,455.68555,269.69336,452.68945,268.54102 M434.71289,326.3877c-1.38281,0-2.30469-0.92188-2.30469-2.30469
                  s0.92188-2.30371,2.30469-2.30371c1.38477,0,2.30664,0.9209,2.30664,2.30371S436.09766,326.3877,434.71289,326.3877"/>
                 <path class="selector-icon__img" d="M420.42383,320.16504c-4.60742,1.15234-9.21875,1.61328-13.36523,1.61328
                  c-11.52344,0-25.12109-4.37891-32.26563-10.37109v-17.28418c0-1.38281-0.92188-2.30469-2.30469-2.30469
                  s-2.30469,0.92188-2.30469,2.30469v18.4375c0,0.69043,0.23047,1.38281,0.69141,1.61328
                  c8.98828,8.06543,24.89063,12.21484,36.18359,12.21484c4.37891,0,9.44727-0.69238,14.28906-1.84473
                  c1.15039-0.23047,2.07227-1.6123,1.61133-2.76563C422.73047,320.62598,421.57617,319.7041,420.42383,320.16504"/>
                </a>
                <a class="selector-icon selector-icon--connect">
                 <g class="selector-circle">
                  <g>
                   <defs>
                    <rect id="SVGID_5_" y="271.98047" width="323.42188" height="323.42969"/>
                   </defs>
                   <clipPath id="SVGID_6_">
                    <use xlink:href="#SVGID_5_"  overflow="visible"/>
                   </clipPath>
                   <path clip-path="url(#SVGID_6_)" fill="#E0B83B" d="M323.42578,433.69727c0,89.3125-72.40088,161.71289-161.71338,161.71289
                    C72.40088,595.41016,0,523.00977,0,433.69727c0-89.31152,72.40088-161.71289,161.7124-161.71289
                    C251.0249,271.98438,323.42578,344.38574,323.42578,433.69727"/>
                  </g>
                 </g>
                 <path class="selector-icon__img" d="M192.06689,374.06055h-12.22168v-5.07422c0-1.14648-0.93359-2.0791-2.0791-2.0791
                  c-1.14746,0-2.08008,0.93262-2.08008,2.0791v5.07422h-25.55176v-5.07422c0-1.14648-0.93359-2.0791-2.08008-2.0791
                  s-2.08008,0.93262-2.08008,2.0791v5.07422h-12.2207c-3.88086,0-7.03711,3.15527-7.03711,7.03418v57.76563
                  c0,3.87988,3.15625,7.03613,7.03711,7.03613h58.31348c3.87988,0,7.03613-3.15625,7.03613-7.03613v-57.76563
                  C199.10303,377.21582,195.94678,374.06055,192.06689,374.06055 M130.87451,392.52441h64.06934v46.33594
                  c0,1.58594-1.29004,2.87695-2.87695,2.87695h-58.31348c-1.58789,0-2.87891-1.29102-2.87891-2.87695V392.52441z M148.0542,384.27148
                  c1.14648,0,2.08008-0.93359,2.08008-2.0791v-3.97266h25.55176v3.97266c0,1.14551,0.93262,2.0791,2.08008,2.0791
                  c1.14551,0,2.0791-0.93359,2.0791-2.0791v-3.97266h12.22168c1.58691,0,2.87695,1.28906,2.87695,2.875v7.27051h-64.06934v-7.27051
                  c0-1.58594,1.29102-2.875,2.87891-2.875h12.2207v3.97266C145.97412,383.33789,146.90771,384.27148,148.0542,384.27148"/>
                 <path class="selector-icon__img" d="M138.70068,416.73438h9.90332c1.14746,0,2.08008-0.93359,2.08008-2.0791v-9.35449
                  c0-1.14648-0.93262-2.08008-2.08008-2.08008h-9.90332c-1.14648,0-2.08008,0.93359-2.08008,2.08008v9.35449
                  C136.62061,415.80078,137.5542,416.73438,138.70068,416.73438 M146.5249,412.5752h-5.74414v-5.19531h5.74414V412.5752z"/>
                 <path class="selector-icon__img" d="M157.9585,416.73438h9.90332c1.14746,0,2.0791-0.93359,2.0791-2.0791v-9.35449
                  c0-1.14648-0.93164-2.08008-2.0791-2.08008h-9.90332c-1.14746,0-2.08008,0.93359-2.08008,2.08008v9.35449
                  C155.87842,415.80078,156.81104,416.73438,157.9585,416.73438 M160.03662,407.37988h5.74609v5.19531h-5.74609V407.37988z"/>
                 <path class="selector-icon__img" d="M177.76611,416.73438h9.90332c1.14648,0,2.08008-0.93359,2.08008-2.0791v-9.35449
                  c0-1.14648-0.93359-2.08008-2.08008-2.08008h-9.90332c-1.14746,0-2.08008,0.93359-2.08008,2.08008v9.35449
                  C175.68604,415.80078,176.61865,416.73438,177.76611,416.73438 M179.84521,407.37988h5.74609v5.19531h-5.74609V407.37988z"/>
                 <path class="selector-icon__img" d="M138.70068,435.99121h9.90332c1.14746,0,2.08008-0.93164,2.08008-2.0791v-9.35254
                  c0-1.14746-0.93262-2.08008-2.08008-2.08008h-9.90332c-1.14648,0-2.08008,0.93262-2.08008,2.08008v9.35254
                  C136.62061,435.05957,137.5542,435.99121,138.70068,435.99121 M146.5249,431.83301h-5.74414v-5.19531h5.74414V431.83301z"/>
                 <path class="selector-icon__img" d="M157.9585,435.99121h9.90332c1.14746,0,2.0791-0.93164,2.0791-2.0791v-9.35254
                  c0-1.14746-0.93164-2.08008-2.0791-2.08008h-9.90332c-1.14746,0-2.08008,0.93262-2.08008,2.08008v9.35254
                  C155.87842,435.05957,156.81104,435.99121,157.9585,435.99121 M160.03662,426.6377h5.74609v5.19531h-5.74609V426.6377z"/>
                 <path class="selector-icon__img" d="M177.76611,435.99121h9.90332c1.14648,0,2.08008-0.93164,2.08008-2.0791v-9.35254
                  c0-1.14746-0.93359-2.08008-2.08008-2.08008h-9.90332c-1.14746,0-2.08008,0.93262-2.08008,2.08008v9.35254
                  C175.68604,435.05957,176.61865,435.99121,177.76611,435.99121 M179.84521,426.6377h5.74609v5.19531h-5.74609V426.6377z"/>
                </a>
            </svg>
            <p class="selector-block__title selector-block__title--join heading--2">Join</p>
            <p class="selector-block__title selector-block__title--learn heading--2">Learn</p>
            <p class="selector-block__title selector-block__title--connect heading--2">Connect</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col--6-12 col__m--12-12 col--flex-col">
        <div class="selector-block__text selector-block__text--mia open" id="mia">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, no purto sonet utinam has. Ex his duis aperiri facilisi, labores nominavi reprimique cum ne, ad torquatos suscipiantur definitionem sea. Aeque nobis salutandi ei quo, nec et dicam definitiones. Nec ei harum adipisci, reque justo ius eu. Nec an prima ceteros scribentur, dicta soluta ponderum no mel. Alii molestiae referrentur no pro.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Its unclear from you question and fiddle what you expect to see...SVG elements like path or rectangle etc... are not positioned with css... SVG (scaleable vector graphics) are positioned relative to the co-ordinates defined in the viewBox attribute.... css flex rules do not apply.....eg. <path d="........." style="fill:none" fill="red"></path>....

Comment: You can see in the fiddle if you play around with the size of the preview window, that the svg will scale up or down as required to fill the width available. The height of it also changes, and affects the height of the parent grey box (this is what I want to happen). However, in IE11, the height of the svg doesn't automatically scale, rather it stays set as 150px (the browser default) due to me not setting an explicit height. This means that the paths within the svg extend out of the grey box, rather than making the grey box larger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it turns out that if no height is explicitly set, ie11 will render all svgs with a 150px height.

I managed to get around this by working out the ratio of height to width and then using jquery to get the width of the svg on page load and then applying the calculations to set an explicit height.